# How to multiply two dataframes with same structure and same column names containing digits?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to multiply two dataframes (only the column containing digits). Both dataframes contains both digits column and character column.
[image]

Can anyone suggest a solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Please remove the image and replace it with reproducible data as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df1 * df2`
,
equivalent to `df1.multiply(df2)` or `df1.mul(df2)`

```
df1
###
Name    a  b
Apple   2  3
Orange  4  2

df2
###
Name    a  b
Apple   1  2
Orange  3  3
```

```
# multiply df1 and df2
df1 * df2
###
Name     a  b
Apple    2  6
Orange  12  6
```

---

If we got different index or column,

```
df3
### different columns
Name    c  d
Apple   1  2
Orange  3  3

df4
### different indexes
Name     a  b
Banana   1  2
Avocado  3  3

df5
### with other string cols
Name   string_col1 string_col2  a  b
Apple           US    Facebook  1  2
Orange         AUS   Instagram  3  3
```

Multiply with `df1`

```
df1 * df3
###
Name     a   b   c   d
Apple  NaN NaN NaN NaN
Orange NaN NaN NaN NaN


df1 * df4
###
Name      a   b
Apple   NaN NaN
Avocado NaN NaN
Banana  NaN NaN
Orange  NaN NaN

df1 * df5 # same as df5 * df1
###
Name     a  b  string_col1  string_col2
Apple    2  6          NaN          NaN
Orange  12  6          NaN          NaN
```

For preserving other info, kind of like assigning block,

```
# take out other info to new dataframe df_out
df_out = df5.loc[:,['string_col1', 'string_col2']]

# take columns would be calculated from df5
# multiply with df1
# assign them to new dataframe df_out whose name are `a` and `b`.
df_out[['a','b']] = df1 * df5[['a', 'b']]

df_out
###
Name   string_col1 string_col2   a  b
Apple           US    Facebook   2  6
Orange         AUS   Instagram  12  6
```

---

### What if `df5` and `df6` have other info we wanna preserve?

```
df5
###
Name   string_col1 string_col2  a  b
Apple           US    Facebook  1  2
Orange         AUS   Instagram  3  3

df6
###
Name   string_col1 string_col2  a  b
Apple           US    Facebook  2  3
Orange         AUS   Instagram  4  2

# say, we wanna preserve info from df5
preserved_info = df5.loc[:,:'string_col2']
calculation = df5[['a', 'b']] * df6[['a', 'b']]
df_out = pd.concat([preserved_info, calculation], axis=1)
df_out
###
Name   string_col1 string_col2   a  b
Apple           US    Facebook   2  6
Orange         AUS   Instagram  12  6
```

#### Method 2

```
df7 = pd.DataFrame({
    'string_col1': ['US', 'AUS'],
    'string_col2': ['Facebook', 'Instagram'],
    'a': [1, 3],
    'b': [2, 3]
}, index=['Apple', 'Orange'])
df7.columns.name = 'Name'

df8 = pd.DataFrame({
    'string_col1': ['FR', 'UK'],
    'string_col2': ['Microsoft', 'TSMC'],
    'c': [2, 4],
    'd': [3, 2]
}, index=['Cherry', 'Blueberry'])
df8.columns.name = 'Name'

df7
###
Name   string_col1 string_col2  a  b
Apple           US    Facebook  1  2
Orange         AUS   Instagram  3  3



df8
###
Name      string_col1 string_col2  c  d
Cherry             FR   Microsoft  2  3
Blueberry          UK        TSMC  4  2
```

Fetch out numerical part into NumPy format then we don't need identical rows and columns.

```
calculation = df7[['a', 'b']].to_numpy() * df8[['c', 'd']].to_numpy()
info = df7.loc[:,:'string_col2']
df_out = pd.concat([info, pd.DataFrame(calculation, index=df7.index, columns=['e', 'f'])], axis=1)
df_out
###
       string_col1 string_col2   e  f
Apple           US    Facebook   2  6
Orange         AUS   Instagram  12  6
```

Comment: Does it affect the first column(Names) when multiplying@Baron Legendre

Comment: It is element-wise multiplication. actually, Apple and Orange are set to be index, and Name is actually the column's name. Though it mimics NumPy's element-wise multiplication, in Pandas you have to make sure the index's and column's alignment.

Comment: What if I have first three column have string values and remaining column name is `a` and `b` in the above example?Can I get the correct multiplied value in the third dataframe?@Baron Legendre

Comment: Yes, you can, just like Google Sheet or Excel, assign some part for the calculated outcome, and another part for other string Infos.

Comment: what if `df1` have the same column names like `df5`? When I give `df_out[['a','b']] = df1[['a','b'] * df5[['a', 'b']]` `a` and `b` column becomes `NaN`@Baron Legendre

Comment: I've updated the post, we can utilize `concat` to combine them into `df_out`

Comment: In my case,index of two dataframe are different.Is that the reason for `NaN`values in the output.If yes , how can I make the two dataframe index same?@Baron Legendre

Comment: Yes, we can, I've updated the post, put them into NumPy array, after finish calculation, assign the result to construct new `df_out`

Answer (score 0):

Sort the values in both the dataframes so that they have same values at same indexes:

```
cols = ["a", "b"]
(df.sort_values("name")[cols] * df1.sort_values("name")[cols])\
    .assign(name=df.name.sort_values())

    a   b   name
0   2   6   apple
1   12  6   orange
```